# "NZEC" Error in the "Life, the Universe and Everything" problem

Tags: python-3.6

This is the problem presented in the question by codechef
Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at the input are integers of one or two digits.

Example
Input:
1
2
Output:
1
2

I tried approaching this problem by setting up a while loop which would accept all inputs, except 42 and return the same input back to the user. Upon encountering 42 I used the sys.exit() function to exit the program

```
import sys
number=int()
while number != 42:
    number = int(input('enter any number '))
    print(number)
    if number == 42:
        sys.exit("yup that's 42 ")
```

Instead of getting a successful submission I'm getting an NZEC Error

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the script by giving a message, it is considered to be an error and returns exit code `1`. I tested this by running the script and then executing `echo $?` to check the previous exit code.

You should print the message normally first, then `sys.exit()`.

---

It's mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) as well:

> If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like.
>
> If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.